# How to test class called or not using mocha & chai with sinon TDD?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tdd, chai, sinon

I want to test class called or not in nodejs, mocha & chai with sinon. I tried with stub but not worked as what I expected.

someMiddleware.js

```
module.export.someMiddleware = async(req,res,next)=>{
const responseData = await someReturnFunction(req);

if (!responseData || responseData == null) { 
      throw new SomeExtendedErrrorClass("stringArg");
    }
res.send(responseData);
}
```

testFile.js

```
sinon
      .stub(someMiddleWare , "someReturnFunction")
      .returns(null);
    const stubClass = sinon.stub(SomeExtendedErrrorClass, "constructor");
    someMiddleware(req, res, next);
    expect(stubClass).to.have.be.called;
```

Even the SomeExtendedErrrorClass called, sinon not detected.

Comment: Where do `someReturnFunction` and `SomeClass` come from? Show the code

Comment: On another file so just require() used to import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinon does not support stub standalone function or class imported from other modules. You need to use [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/), we will be using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to construct our seams.

E.g.

`someMiddleware.js`:

```js
const someReturnFunction = require('./someReturnFunction');
const SomeExtendedErrrorClass = require('./SomeExtendedErrrorClass');

module.exports.someMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const responseData = await someReturnFunction(req);

  if (!responseData || responseData == null) {
    throw new SomeExtendedErrrorClass('stringArg');
  }
  res.send(responseData);
};
```

`SomeExtendedErrrorClass.js`:

```js
class SomeExtendedErrrorClass extends Error {}
```

`someReturnFunction.js`:

```js
async function someReturnFunction() {
  return 'real implementation';
}
```

`someMiddleware.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SomeExtendedErrrorClass = require('./SomeExtendedErrrorClass');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('68640048', () => {
  it('should get and send response data', async () => {
    const someReturnFunctionStub = sinon.stub().resolves('teresa teng');

    const { someMiddleware } = proxyquire('./someMiddleware', {
      './someReturnFunction': someReturnFunctionStub,
    });
    const mReq = {};
    const mRes = { send: sinon.stub() };
    await someMiddleware(mReq, mRes);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mRes.send, 'teresa teng');
  });

  it('should throw error', async () => {
    const someReturnFunctionStub = sinon.stub().resolves(null);
    const { someMiddleware } = proxyquire('./someMiddleware', {
      './someReturnFunction': someReturnFunctionStub,
    });

    const mReq = {};
    const mRes = { send: sinon.stub() };
    await expect(someMiddleware(mReq, mRes)).to.eventually.rejectedWith(SomeExtendedErrrorClass);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  68640048
    ✓ should get and send response data
    ✓ should throw error


  2 passing (10ms)
```